# Official mutations on left 4 dead 2

Tags: left-4-dead-2, mods

I just bought Left 4 Dead 2, and I noticed there's a "mutation" (mod) to play, but only one per week (I think it's per week).

Is there a way to play past official mutations, or is it intended for only one to be available at the same time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is now possible to play old mutations; when you select Mutation, the last option in the menu is "Change Mutation," and there's a pretty good list of Mutations you can play, in 1-, 4-, or 8-player games.

Note that, because there are a couple of dozen available mutations (counting all modes), it can be hard to get a game going unless you're willing to wait a while or invite some friends. If you want to play *soon*, invite friends or get used to bots. ("Four Swordsmen" is awful with bots, by the way. If you get grabbed by a Smoker on a ledge, your teammates can't figure out how to get to his ledge and stab him.)

Answer (score 2):

If mutations work like dev-picks servers on Quake Live do, then no, there is no easy way to play past mutations.

Chances are, however, that are not-as-easy ways to play mutations. Often, you'll be able to regenerate the effect with existing cvars -- usually cheating-protected ones, however. For example last week's "dev pick servers" for QL was slow motion servers, aka `timescale 0.5`.

Answer (score 2):

In principle, you cannot play past mutations. You can play only the week it is out.

But in the last weeks it happened that Valve decided to repeat some successful mutations, like **Chainsaw Massacre**, for example.

It could happen also Valve decides that some mutations will become "always-playable" like they did with **Realism Versus**.

Comment: This is no longer accurate; you can now select which Mutation to play.